# Add and Substract one Row value to another row value in same table using mysql

Tags: mysql

Below is my table `tbl_wallet`. I want to add and subtract amount in same table addition and subtraction on the basis of credit and debit key

| sno | w_userid | w_amount | w_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 263 | 100 | credit |
| 2 | 263 | 200 | credit |
| 3 | 263 | 100 | credit |
| 4 | 263 | 100 | debit |

Below is my query for getting detail

```
SELECT wl.w_userid
       , wl.w_type
       , wl.w_amount
       , DATE_FORMAT(w_date,' %D %M %Y %r') AS w_date
       , SUM(w_amount) 
FROM  tbl_wallet AS wl 
WHERE wl.w_userid=263 
ORDER BY wl.w_date DESC;
```

But i want the output like Below

| sno | w_userid | w_amount | w_type | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 263 | 100 | credit | 100 |
| 2 | 263 | 200 | credit | 300 |
| 3 | 263 | 100 | credit | 400 |
| 4 | 263 | 100 | debit | 300 |

Comment: It would be nice if sample data matched query - where is w_date in data?

Comment: Also search for mysql running total and mysql cumulative total and research window functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *,
       SUM(CASE w_type WHEN 'credit' THEN w_amount
                       WHEN 'debit'  THEN -w_amount
                       ELSE 0 
                       END) OVER (PARTITION BY w_userid
                                  ORDER BY sno ASC) AS Balance
FROM source_table
```